# Why are negative frequencies of a discrete fourier transform appear where high frequencies are supposed to be?

Tags: fft, dft

i am very new to this topic, please help me understand why this happens...

if i make the dft of a cos wave

```
cos(w*x)=0.5*(exp(i*w*x)+exp(-i*w*x))
```

i expect to get one peak at the "w" frequency, and the negative one "-w" should not be visible, but it appears at the far end of the spectrum where higher frequencies are supposed to be...

why? do high frequencies produce the same effect as negative ones?

if you imagine a wave with frequency equal to `3*pi/2`, that is, `(0, 3pi/2, 6pi/2, 9pi/2)`, it does seem like a wave with negative frequency `-pi/2 (0, -pi/2, -pi, -3pi/2)`

is that the reason to what is happening? please help!

Comment: I think you might have a lot more luck asking this in the math stack exchange; if you do post there try to use the LaTeX formatting to ask the question. http://math.stackexchange.com/  // http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex

Comment: @AnotherUser [EE StackExchange](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/) might also be appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

High frequencies between the Nyquist rate (Fs/2) and the Sample rate (Fs) alias to negative frequencies, due to sampling above the Nyquist rate.  And vice versa, negative frequencies alias to the top half of an FFT.  "Alias" means you can't tell those frequencies apart at that sample rate, due to the fact that sampling sinewaves at either of those frequencies at that sample rate can produce absolutely identical sets of samples.